# Python - need to change a list with uppercase and lowercase words into all lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project is pretty basic... I need to take a text file of the gettysburg address and count the number of words and the number of unique words.  I've gotten pretty much all the way to the end but its double counting words that are the same just with a capital first letter -- ie But and but.  I'm not sure how to fix this :(  Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    getty = open('Gettysburgaddress.txt','r')
    lines = getty.readlines()
    getty.close()

    index = 0
    while index < len(lines):
       lines[index] = lines[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1

    words = [word for line in lines for word in line.split()]

    size = len(words)

    print('\nThere are', size,'words in the Gettysburg Address.\n')

    unique = list(set(words))

    size_unique = len(unique)

    print('There are', size_unique,'unique words in the Gettysburg Address.\n')

    unique.sort()

    print('Sorted order of unique words:', unique)

    close = input('')

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowercase the words while collecting them:

```
words = [word.lower() for line in lines for word in line.split()]
```

or when creating the set of unique words:

```
unique = list(set(word.lower() for word in words))
```

You could simplify your file-loading code a little more:

```
with open('Gettysburgaddress.txt','r') as getty:
    words = [word.lower() for line in getty for word in line.split()]
```

This loads the file into a list of lower-cased words in one step, where `with` statement also takes care of closing the file again.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Didn't realize you could just add the lower command early on!

Comment: You could use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` in case someone used fancy Unicode typesetting.